ENOMEM error during node HTTP requests even with plenty of memory
I'm running into a frustrating ENOMEM error in node during HTTP requests. I suspect macOS is somehow the culprit since node seems to have plenty of memory. The basic idea of my script is to page through a search REST API and collect a modest (<30,000) number of items. The items are not huge in size, either. The script has a recursive search function like:
let all_items = []

async function search(start = 0) {
    params.set('start', start)
    const r = await fetch(`${options.url}/api/search/?${params.toString()}`, { headers: headers })
    if (!r.ok) console.error(`HTTP error: ${r.status} ${r.statusText}`)
    const d = await r.json()
    // API error messages
    if (d.error) throw new Error(`${d.code} ${d.error}: ${d.error_description}`)

    all_items.push(...data.results)
    const count = all_items.length
    if (count < data.available) {
        console.log(`Getting items ${count + 1} through ${count + LENGTH}...`)
        search(count + LENGTH)
    }
}

This always hits an ENOMEM error eventually before finishing:
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13185
      Error.captureStackTrace(err);
            ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13185:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
    at async search (file:///Users/ephetteplace/Code/aVAULT/scripts/retention/ret.js:56:15) {
  [cause]: Error: connect ENOMEM IP:443 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
      at internalConnect (node:net:1093:16)
      at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (node:internal/async_hooks:464:18)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (node:net:1492:9)
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:132:8) {
    errno: -12,
    code: 'ENOMEM',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: IP,
    port: 443
  }
}

Node.js v22.8.0

I've tried so many things:

node --max-old-space-size=4076 ... & NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=4076" node ...
run node --expose-gc and manually trigger garbage collection global.gc() before search recurs
close all other running applications to increase free memory
reboot

I tried process.memoryUsage() while running the script and memory usage never goes above 150MB, nowhere near node's max. Dumping heap profiles with --heap-prof shows the same thing. What is happening? Is it some lower level OS layer that's running out of memory?
I know I can rewrite the script to go through a set number of items at a time, taking a start and stop number, I'm just flummoxed why node is hitting this memory error.
